# Un'ora e mezzo o mezza?

Tags: grammatical-number, agreement

Ciao a tutti. Ho in effetti due domande. La prima è: Si dice "un'ora e mezzo" oppure "un'ora e mezza"? E la seconda: quando "un'ora e mezzo/a" è il soggetto di una frase, deve essere la terza persona singolare o plurale?

Cioè … quale di queste frasi è corretta?

1. Ci vuole un'ora e mezzo.
2. Ci vuole un'ora e mezza.
3. Ci vogliono un'ora e mezzo.
4. Ci vogliono un'ora e mezza.

Grazie in anticipo.

Comment: Domanda interessante: io ho sempre sentito "ci vuole un'ora e mezza", ma una ricerca su Internet mi fa vedere che "un'ora e mezzo" è anche corretto!

Comment: Se ne parla qui: http://www.corriere.it/Rubriche/Scioglilingua/2005/22luglio.shtml.

Comment: [Qui](http://www.lastampa.it/2016/02/12/italia/cronache/il-paese-che-doveva-morire-si-apre-al-mondo-nuovo-e-scopre-di-avere-un-futuro-NCs6MZs2x07eqNs4TZGBOK/pagina.html) trovi l'esempio "Ma ci vuole un’ora e mezzo di auto".

Comment: Ma in [questo esame di italiano della Società Dante Alighieri](http://www.wp.chianciano.scuolevaldichiana.org/wp-content/uploads/Docenti/Materiale%2520Didattico/Secondaria%2520I%2520Grado/A1-ascleg.pdf) trovi la frase "Da lì ci vuole un'ora e mezza".

Comment: "Ci vuole un'ora e mezzo" e "Ci vuole un'ora e mezza" sono considerate corrette.

Comment: Per le alternative "mezzo" e "mezza" ho trovato una spiegazione nel libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* di Vittorio Coletti. Ma non trovo nulla che spieghi perché "un'ora e mezzo (o mezza)" è da considerarsi singolare e non plurale.

Comment: Ecco quello che trovato nel libro sopra citato nel prossimo commento.

Comment: "La presenza o meno dell'accordo distingue anche l'uso aggettivale e quello sostantivale di *mezzo* in espressioni come «le sette e mezza» (trattato da aggettivo e concordato col nome femminile *ora* sottinteso) e «le sette e mezzo» (cioè *un mezzo*, con *mezzo* trattato regolarmente da sostantivo morfologicamente autonomo)".

Comment: Il femminile è più corretto. Il maschile è più dialettale: non sentirai mai un meridionale dirlo

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Igino! Penso che il tuo post non possa considerarsi una risposta completa e ben argomentata alla domanda. Per questa ragione, l'ho convertita in un commento.

Comment: Anche se sono corrette entrambe le frasi, direi che a mio avviso, è più corretta "un'ora e mezza" se non altro perché mezza (che dipende da ora) continua il "sesso" di ora, infatti ora, ha l'articolo indeterminativo apostrofato (femminile), quindi continuerei con mezza (sempre al femminile)

Comment: @JoeTaras: Ma, come spiega Vittorio Coletti nel brano che ho riportato, "mezzo" è anche un sostantivo maschile.

Comment: @Charo: Sì, giusto. Però preferisco come aggettivo ;)

Comment: @JoeTaras: È il tuo gusto personale, ma puoi vedere [qui](http://www.corriere.it/Rubriche/Scioglilingua/2005/22luglio.shtml) che molte fonti autorevoli considerano la forma "mezzo" più corretta.

Comment: @Charo: Sì, effettivamente leggendo il contenuto del link, mi è caduto il mondo addosso :D Grazie, cercherò di correggermi d'ora in avanti

Comment: Anche per l'orario si dice mezzo
perché l'ora viene frazionata e le frazioni sono al maschile.

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE, @marco33! Puoi argomentare maggiormente la tua risposta?

Answer (score 7):

Le espressioni usate sono:

> Ci vuole un'ora e mezza, oppure
>
> Ci vuole un'ora e mezzo

[L'accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/mezzo-mezza) ritiene che entrambe le forme siano corrette:

> - «***Come di deve dire, le tre e mezzo o le tre e mezza? Come preferite***. Potete usare la forma le tre e mezzo, cioè le tre più il mezzo, la metà di un'ora, oppure le tre e mezza, sottintendendo ora.
> - ***Si dice, invece, la mezza per indicare la mezz'ora dopo le dodici***, cioè mezzogiorno e trenta minuti, o anche la mezzanotte e mezzo, cioè le ore zero e trenta minuti; è corretto, ma meno comune (e quindi potrebbe causare equivoci), anche l'uso di la mezza per indicare la mezz'ora dopo un'ora qualsiasi già indicata: "Il treno parte alle tre e quaranta: vediamoci alla mezza (cioè alle tre e trenta)".»

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un%27ora%20e%20mezza%2Cun%27ora%20e%20mezzo&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%27ora%20e%20mezza%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%27ora%20e%20mezzo%3B%2Cc0)*** mostra che entrambi gli  usi  "mezzo o mezza" sono diffusi.

Dello stesso parere sembra essere  [Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_106.html)

> Nelle espressioni di tempo (in questo caso viene sottinteso il sostantivo ora): si scriverà e si dirà, per esempio, sono le otto e mezzo o si preferirà le otto e mezza?
>
> - In entrambi i casi, anche se forte è la propensione funzionale di mezzo ad avverbio e la grammatica, stricto sensu, consiglierebbe l’uso della forma invariata mezzo, la norma, ***vista la quantità di oscillazioni nell’uso – e non da tempi recenti – lascia facoltà di libera scelta. Insomma, entrambe le scelte (mezzo invariato o mezzo/a/i/e, cioè flesso) sono ammesse.***
> - ***Ovviamente, si dice esclusivamente la mezza per indicare le ore 12.30 o le ore 0.30;***  peraltro, va estendendosi l’uso di la mezza per indicare il momento in cui sono passati 30 minuti dopo una qualunque ora, a patto che il contesto sia chiaro: senti, anziché alle 7 e 40 troviamoci alla mezza, dove “mezza” vale ‘7.30’.

Comment: Come si può vedere nel brano che ho riportato in un mio commento, anche Vittorio Coletti dà una spiegazione di questo fenomeno (alternanza di "mezzo" e "mezza").  Ma, come ho detto prima, non si spiega perché "un'ora e mezzo (o mezza)" è da considerarsi singolare e non plurale.

Comment: @Charo - sì, penso che l'uso del verbo al singolare sia indiomatico, come per altre espressioni tipo: ci vuole  kilo e mezzo..., ci vuole un anno e mezzo, ci vuole un metro e mezzo di... etc.

Answer (score -1):

Certo, per chilo (kg), anno, metro (m.), essendo parole maschili, è giusto dire:
Un kg e mezzo, 
Un anno e mezzo,
Un metro e mezzo.
Ma riferendosi alle ore o ad una sola ora, a mio parere ci vorrebbe sempre "mezza" perché il soggetto resta sempre l'ora o le ore che sono entrambe di genere femminile.

Comment: Mmmmm... Non è quello che pensa Vittorio Coletti (vedi il mio commento sopra).

Comment: Prima di rispondere hai letto i commenti che sono sotto alla domanda da più di sei mesi, Manuela...?